# How do I set up my out of office in Gmail for G Suite for a specific time frame?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business

I've googled everything and watched multiple YouTube videos and cannot find this answer.  How do I set up my out of office in GSuite for a specific time frame?

Example:

I'll be out of the office from 3-5pm and I want to set up an email out of office triggered ONLY during that time frame.  Right now I only see the option of 12:00 AM on the start date and ends at 11:59 PM on the end date.  I need to be able to specify time frames.  Is this possible?